# How to hide :before content in parent by hover on child?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this in html :

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of menus" class="{{ menu.attributes.class }} menu-items" [attr.data-title]="menu.label">
    <a [routerLink]="[menu.url||'/']" [queryParams]="menu.refParameter3 ? menu.refParameter3:{}"(click)="clicked = true;selectMenu(menu)">
        <i *ngIf="menu.icon" class="{{menu.icon}}"></i>
        <span>{{menu.label}}</span>
        <i *ngIf="menu.children && menu.children.length" class="subarrow fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>

    <z-menu class="childrens" *ngIf="menu.children && menu.children.length" [menus]="menu.children" [parent]="menu.label"></z-menu>
</li>
```

In css i have this:

```
.menu-items:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 100px;
  left: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  visibility: 1s
}
```

So what i want is when i hover on li that have `childrens` class as parent to hide before content on parent element. Any suggestion?

Comment: First of all, please provide a _proper_ [mcve]. That angular stuff is not “runable” to any of us here without setting up a complete project; so please create a static HTML example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve!

Do you want to show the `:before` selector by default and then hide it once you hover over a `li` element that has a `childrens` class? Is that what you want??

> And please do as @CBroe suggested.

Comment: what do i do from @CBroe suggestion ? because has is not supported by any browser ?